# Custom BackButton on NavigationController not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to use a custom back button in `UINavigationController` but the image is not appearing.

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "Back-50")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "Back-50")
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong with this code.

Comment: Which view controller are you expecting the button to appear at ?

Comment: all the controllers other than Root ViewController @A-Live

Comment: Then it appears to work.

Comment: Yeah, really baffled what might be wrong. @A-Live

Comment: Are you trying to set a entirely different back button or add an image beside the default back button? The backIndicatorImage is used to show an image beside the backButton

Comment: I m trying to use a back button image like < symbol which has 50 px height width  @PradeepK

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, I don't see what is not working.

Comment: The Screenshot icon appearing is not the BackImage I have given. @A-Live

Comment: Well, then you either gave the wrong image or didn't draw it correctly.

Comment: But when I m not even giving any image that clickable icon is there @A-Live

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, you should use UIAppearance.

Like this

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-back"]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-back"]];

    return YES;
}
```

In swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "")

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just your image to appear as the back button then set the tintColor of the navigationBar to clear color and then set an image based UIBarButtonItem as the backBarButtonItem of navigationItem of the controller.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "back")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

This will make the default back button image (<) not appear (infact it appears but its in clear color so not visible) and just show the back image.

Comment: This shall be added for the main View controller or the traversed View controllers?

Comment: Thanks pradeep. I tried your code and Back button Image appears now. But the other Button image ( as in the image in question )is also appearing at the same time.

Comment: In the image that you've attached its not clear whats your actual back button image. Can you specify how it actually appears and how you want it to actually appear?

Comment: This should be added to the main view controller and all traversed view controllers. The beauty is that it will be used only when a view controller is just below the top view controller in the navigation flow. Its not same as leftBarButtonItem. Its used when this view controller's navigationItem is just below the top most view controller in the navigation stack. Looking at the image it seems like the default < button is shown. You can hide it by setting the tintColor to clearColor as I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: If this works please accept my answer so that others can benefit out of it

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement those line of code in the targeted viewcontroller that means the controller you will push, because you want to customize back item button which active only when you push a viewcontroller into navigation controller stack. Your code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Back-50"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "back")

func back(){
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        UIButton *btnLeft=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnLeft.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 40);
        [btnLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickBackBarItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btnLeft setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnLeft];

-(void)onClickBackBarItem:(id)sender
{
   // ** your stuff ** //
}
```

May this help yoy

Comment: I m actually new to IOS environment , may I have the swift code

Answer (score 1):

Try this it`s working for me.

```
var BackButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: 
UIImage(named: "Back-50"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "back")

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = BackButton

func back()
{
   // your backcontroller code here....
}
```